# How do I get an array in JSON and loop through it to get its elements

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

In C# I make a GET reqeust to get som JSON data. In this JSON data there is an array, which I want to return the elements in this data. I'm using Json.NET to try to achieve this.

Here is my C# code to get a property in the JSON file.

```
public static string sendRequest(string url, string method) 
{
    try
    {
        // Set reqiued information for api
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(main_url + url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Current_Access_Token);
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json;v=1";
        httpWebRequest.Method = method;

        // Get adn return responses
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string respStr = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return respStr;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No response");
    }
    return "";
}
public static string GetUserName()
{
    string resp = sendRequest("api.php/currentCustomer/", "GET");
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(resp);
    JToken Juser = jObject["response"];
    string UserName = (string)Juser["data"]["customer"]["name"];
    return UserName;
}
```

The code above is how I return the name of a customer under customer. But under customer there is an array, "active_digital_subscriptions". In this array there is 2 elements which I want to access and save in setting.setting. "active_digital_subscriptions" only contains string.

JSON data:

```
{  
   "response":{  
      "code":200,
      "status":"success",
      "data":{  
         "customer":{  
            "id":"109701",
            "email":"ahjune152@one.com",
            "name":"ahjune152",
            "first_name":"Loc",
            "last_name":"Dai Le",
            "registration_date":"2015-06-17",
            "last_login_date":"2015-11-05",
            "is_newsletter_subscriber":"1",
            "digital_password":"YOtI1cuzL18dO3i9T9CBVCiX3lQa3iIPhcWDgiwHxxI=",
            "language":{  
               "id":"1",
               "name":"American english",
               "code":"en"
            },
            "currency":{  
               "id":"1",
               "name":"Danske kroner",
               "sign":"DKK",
               "code":"DKK",
               "number":"208"
            },
            "preferred_platforms":[  

            ],
            "active_digital_subscriptions":[  
               {  
                  "plan_id":"246",
                  "plan_title":"VIP Partner"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to create `JProperty` and `JArray`

Comment: What kind of "exception handling" is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) and [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) for this purpose.  Both support [JSONPath query syntax](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var userName = (string)Juser.SelectToken("data.customer.name");
var customersItems = Juser.SelectTokens("data.customer.customers_items[*]")
    .Select(t => (string)t)
    .ToArray();
```

`[*]` is a [wildcard](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) that selects all elements in the array.

**Update**

Given your revised JSON, you can get the active user and active subscriptions like so:

```
var userName = (string)Juser.SelectToken("data.customer.name");
var activeSubscriptions = Juser.SelectTokens("data.customer.active_digital_subscriptions[*]")
    .Select(t => new { PlanId = (string)t["plan_id"], PlanTitle = (string)t["plan_title"] })
    .ToArray();
```

Note that the active subscriptions are in an array, so it would appear possible that there could be more than one.  If you know there is only one, you can do

```
var activeSubscription = activeSubscriptions.SingleOrDefault();
```

Here I am returning the subscriptions in an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) but you could define an explicit class if you prefer:

```
public class Subscription
{
    public string PlanId { get; set; }
    public string PlanTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And then do:

```
var activeSubscriptions = Juser.SelectTokens("data.customer.active_digital_subscriptions[*]")
    .Select(t => new Subscription { PlanId = (string)t["plan_id"], PlanTitle = (string)t["plan_title"] })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi @dbc. I tried this, but it does not work. I checked if "customersItem" array is empty, and it is. See my question edit i have uploaded the JSON file, and instead of "customers_item" it is "active_digital_subscriptions". But if I console output this line: string resp = sendRequest("api.php/currentCustomer/", "GET"); The console does not show the whole output. It is missing the array: "active_digital_subscriptions"

Comment: @LocDaiLe - I answered your original question.  But if you have different JSON that you described, `SelectTokens` is still useful but you will need a different query string.  As for your revised question, the JSON you have added is not in fact JSON.  I'm not sure what it is.  Can you include just the JSON string?  You can format and validate it at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: My bad - now I have upload the JSON. Thank you @dbc

Answer (score 1):

You could try this -

```
var subs = (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["response"]["data"]["customer"]["active_digital_subscriptions"];
for (var i = 0; i < subs.Count; ++i)
{
     var id = ((JValue)subs[i]["plan_id"]).Value;
     var title = ((JValue)subs[i]["plan_title"]).Value;
}
```